# Kion "ekipiteco" signifas?

Tags: word-meaning

> La sfero de servoj kaj de komerco konsternas ne nur pro la skalo, sed
> ankaŭ pro la teknika **ekipiteco**, saturiteco per komputiloj, per
> cetera aŭtomata aparataro (Boris Kolker. Vojaĝo en Esperanto-lando, p170).

ekipi-t-eco aŭ ek-ipit-eco? Ĉu ĝi havas rilaton al "teceremonio" vorto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi pensas, ke la baza vorto estas la verbo "ekipi", al kiu [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#ekipi_kd) donas difinon

> Provizi iun aŭ ion per ĉio necesa por la difinita funkcio

Jen estas unu el la ekzemploj

> la fabriko estis ekipita per plej modernaj maŝinoj

Do "ekipita" priskribas ion aŭ iun, kiun oni ekipis (pasiva pasinta adjektiva participo).

La sufikso "-ec" esprimas kvaliton aŭ staton de io aŭ iu, ekz. moleco, blankeco. Ŝajnas al mi, ke la aŭtoro uzas la vorton "ekipiteco" por montri gradon de ekipo (rezulto de la ago ekipi). Pravas, ke la esprimo estas peza kaj mi demandas min, ĉu ne la simpla "ekipo" (vd. PIV) sufiĉas.

Comment: ["-it-eco"](https://reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-2b.html?q=%25iteco) aperas pli ofte, do la aŭtoro ne estas kritikinda.

Comment: Atenton, `ekipita` ne estas io aŭ iu sed la [priskribo de iu aŭ io](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/a-vortoj.html).  `ekipito` [estus iu aŭ io](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/participoj/o-vortoj.html). Mi samopinias, `ekipo` ja sufiĉas, `ekipiteco` estas ebla kunmetaĵo, sed ĝi ankaŭ estas ĝene peza.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, mi reskribis la klarigon de "ekipita". Dankon pro la rimarko.

Answer (score 1):

> ekipi-t-eco aŭ ek-ipit-eco?

Nek, nek:

La neoficialan [sufikson *-t*](https://vortaro.net/#_foliumi_t) oni uzas nur post numeraloj. *ipit* laŭ mia scio ne estas Esperanta morfemo.

Do la [du ebloj legi la vorton *ekipiteco*](http://simplavortaro.org/ser%C4%89o?s=ekipiteco) estas:

- *[ekip](https://vortaro.net/#ekip/_k)·[it](https://vortaro.net/#it_k)·[ec](https://vortaro.net/#ec_k)·[o](https://lernu.net/gramatiko/substantivoj)* (plej verŝajna, eĉ sen kunteksto)
- *[ek](https://vortaro.net/#ek_k)·[ip](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-2a.html?q=-ip)·[it](https://vortaro.net/#it_k)·[ec](https://vortaro.net/#ec_k)·[o](https://lernu.net/gramatiko/substantivoj)*

Pri la unua vidu [la bonan respondon de Juha](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/6358/1576).

La dua ne havas klaran sencon kaj tute ne sencas en la kunteksto de tiu frazo.

> Ĉu ĝi havas rilaton al "teceremonio" vorto?

*te·ceremoni·o* estas *ceremonio* pri / kun / per *teo* (verŝajne la fama [japana teceremonio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japana_teceremonio)). Do krome, ol ke ambaŭ vortoj estas kunmetaĵoj kaj ke eble oni devus ekip·iĝ·i (kaj per iloj kaj vestoj, kaj per la necesa scipovo) por kondukti tian ceremonion, verŝajne ne estas rilato inter ili.

Answer (score 0):

Nu, mi konsentas ke ambaŭ ekipo kaj ekipiteco priskribas la saman aferon, sed ekipiteco pli emfazas la staton de la ekipo nun, kaj eble estis elektita de la skribanto tial.  Uzante iom fuŝitan anglan, la diferenco, laŭ mi, estas la diferenco inter "equipment" kaj "equipped-ness".